# Mobile CSS is The Only CSS Showing... Even on Desktop

Tags: css, mobile, desktop

So I made a website which has two CSS files; one is for regular desktop computers, and one is for mobile devices with a max width of 480px. Something happened while I was editing my website, and now the mobile version is the only CSS that shows.

I have two CSS' linked in my header, both the mobile CSS and regular (desktop) CSS. When I remove the mobile css link, the desktop version of the website shows like it should. However, when the mobile css stylesheet link is in place, only the mobile website is what shows on both desktop and mobile devices.

When you go onto my website on a laptop, the whole page is shoved to the left, and it is only 480px wide. Any idea what is up?

Comment: Some code? Maybe even your file tree?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was a wordpress plugin called "Above the Fold" which was the problem. I had to link the CSS in the footer.